# Как ускорить формирование pdf с помощью tcpdf в laravel?

Tags: laravel, tcpdf

Решил сформировать pdf в проекте laravel, добавил пакет tcpdf через композер, прописал фасад PDF, все по мануалу. Сделал из примера просто pdf с надписью “хеллоу ворлд”, а потом решил сделать фоновую картинку и стилизовать текст html… в общем делал все через фасад, аля PDF::AddPage(), PDF::Image() и т.д, в общем заметил, что уж больно долго формируется документ, воткнул метки времени, показало, документ формируется от 7 до 17 секунд, стандартная картинка А4, 40 кб, выходной документ 80-83 кб… Пробовал сделать тоже самое на нативном php результат максимум 1-2 секунды… Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли возможность ускорить формирование pdf документа? Может есть более скоростная библиотека для формирования pdf?